# How can I make my function url contains efficient?

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I'm using android webview to check URLs of pages. Currently my code is like this

```
if (nurl.contains(".pdf"))
{
//doing stuff
}
else if(nurl.contains(".PDF"))
{
//doing stuff
}
```

How can I make it efficient. I tried using OR operator (||) but its not supported in Android Studio, Java.

Comment: "I tried using And operator (||) but its not supported in Android Studio" - That's OR, and what do you mean it's not supported?

Comment: Sorry! Its typo. I mean OR. When I type ||, its giving me error. Operator || can not be applied to 'java.lang.String', 'java.lang.String'

Comment: `if (nurl.contains(".pdf") || nurl.contains(".PDF"))`

Comment: || does work in Java/Android Studio, but you must do (boolean || boolean), not (String || String).

Comment: "nurl.contains(".pdf")" is a boolean

Comment: Thats Magic! Thank you so much! That worked! Please tell me how can I improve my Android Programming skills.

Comment: @Einar, I didn't mean to reply to Mike, we both posted at the same time. Yes, (nurl.contains(".pdf")) is a boolean.

Comment: @johnisgr8, I'd suggest you practice Java on the following sites http://codingbat.com/java  and https://www.codewars.com/

Comment: @StephanBranczyk, Ah, sorry. Things happen so quickly at stackoverflow :-)

Comment: @Stephan Branczyk Sure! Will do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the filename to upper-case and make just a single `contains` call.

```
if (nurl.toUpperCase().contains(".PDF")) {
    //doing stuff
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, link doesn't end with PDF.

Comment: Fair enough.  Edited accordingly.

Comment: This worked like charm! Your solution looking efficient than my answer. Right?

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you!  Don't forget to upvote and accept this answer!

Comment: Sure! I would like if you can upvote my question too.

Comment: @johnisgr8 - Upvotes should not be used like that.  Upvotes on questions are for well researched, well written questions that are likely to be useful to other people in the future.  In this case, the Q is based on a false premise (that `||` is not supported in Android!)  and is more likely to mislead than to help.

Answer (score 0):

Solution by[Mike M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2850651/mike-m) and  [Stephan Branczyk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/320111/stephan-branczyk)

This worked like charm!

```
if (nurl.contains(".pdf") || nurl.contains(".PDF"))
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I type ||, its giving me error. `Operator || can not be applied to 'java.lang.String', 'java.lang.String'`

I guess that you wrote this:

```
  if (nurl.contains(".pdf" || ".PDF")) {
      //doing stuff
  }
```

That doesn't work in Java.  The compiler is correct.  You cannot "OR" two strings together; see this [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) (*The Conditional Operators* part) for what the `||` operator does, and what its operands must be.

That is what the compiler message is saying: "you can't OR" two strings together.

But here's the real problem ... you *shouldn't* be "OR"-ing the strings.  You should actually be "OR"-ing the results of the `contains` calls.

Java doesn't work like the English language.  In English "does A contain B or C" means "does A contain B or does A contain C".  In Java (and AFAIK all other languages) you need to do the rearrangement yourself ... in an utterance like that.

```
  if (nurl.contains(".pdf") || nurl.contains(".PDF")) {
      //doing stuff
  }
```

---

Having said that, your test is still questionable.  Shouldn't you be testing for URLs that *end with* `".pdf"` or `".PDF"`?

```
  if (nurl.endsWith(".pdf") || nurl.endsWith(".PDF")) {
      //doing stuff
  }
```